# set the datatype dropdown value in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, dropdown, custom-data-type

I'm hoping some one can help. I've create an new page with an umbraco datatype drop down. I have a form in the front end which will create a new page. I was wondering is there a way I can set the value of the dropdown. atm I have just been passing in the value but to no avail. any help given will be greatly appreciated.

kind regards, 
H

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a good solution not too sure if it is the "right" solution but it seems to work 
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/54462-Set-value-of-UmbracoDropDown-programatically